# Jump to third comment

Tags: c#, office-interop

How can open a Word file and jump to third comment of that files automatically if exists using `Office Word-Interop`?

I was tested the `Select` method but need to jump to that comment instead of select the text range.

Comment: The Document object has a [Comments property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word._document.comments(v=office.14).aspx). What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Yes. I know but how  to Jump to that comment automatically after opening the file?

Answer (score 0):

The Microsoft Word Object Model has a [Comments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb211871%28v=office.12%29.aspx) collection.  The third comment in any given Comments collection is probably `Comments(3)`.  (VBA collections are 1-based).

Comment: How Jump to that comment automatically after opening the file?

Comment: See Section 17.5.1 [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd492012(v=office.12).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

In VBA it'll something like this:

```
If ActiveDocument.Comments.Count > 2 Then
    ActiveDocument.Comments(3).Scope.Select
    Application.Selection.StartOf (Word.WdUnits.wdColumn)
End If
```

In plugin c# project very similar:

```
private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    this.Application.DocumentChange += new Word.ApplicationEvents4_DocumentChangeEventHandler(Application_DocumentChange);

}        

void Application_DocumentChange()
{
    if (this.Application.ActiveDocument.Comments.Count > 2 /* && code to check if its first document opening or changing documents */)
    {
        object unit = Word.WdUnits.wdColumn;
        object missing = Type.Missing;

        this.Application.ActiveDocument.Comments[3].Scope.Select();
        this.Application.Selection.StartOf(ref unit, ref missing);
    }
}
```

Comment.Scope is a Word.Range object which points to a location of comment text.
Code first selects comment text and then moves cursor to its beginning.